# value not passing to eithr jquery code or showing in cfdump

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I am running the Code here as like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myjs.js?<cfoutput>#randnumber#</cfoutput>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="own_id.cfm"></script>
<cfdump var="#own_id#">
```

It is throwing as error as:

```
Variable OWN_ID is undefined.
```

Now if i remove the

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'set.cfm',     
            async: false,                   
            data: 'own_id='+own_id,
            success: function(i){   
            }
        });
});
```

Error is throwing on `own_id`. `ReferenceError: own_id is not defined`

own_id.cfm code:

```
<cfsetting showdebugoutput="no">
<cfset own_id = session.id_user>
<cfoutput>#own_id#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **own_id.cfm**, replace the code to this:

```
<cfsetting showdebugoutput="no">
<cfset own_id = session.id_user>
<cfoutput>var own_id = #own_id#;</cfoutput>
```

Otherwise, you are simply outputting the object's value to the page without supplying a variable assignment.

And it's not going to show up in your CF dump because you are calling the CFM template as a JS script file, therefore your CF variable will never be defined to get dumped.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="own_id.cfm"></script>
```

own_id.cfm is not a javascript file so that command is not going to do anything useful.  Given the contents of that file, maybe you want this:

```
<cfinclude template="own_id.cfm">
```

That will solve your undefined variable problem in ColdFusion.  For the jquery part, it might be a simple as surrounding the code block with cfoutput tags and changing this:

```
data: 'own_id='+own_id
```

to this:

```
data: 'own_id='+ #own_id#
```

But it's hard to say because the question does not say where that jquery code is.